# Is the activation energy for vaporization equal to the enthalpy of vaporization?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

When ethanol, say, evaporates, the intermolecular forces between molecules need to be broken. As a vapour, there are no new forces being created, so it is a purely endothermic process, with no "hump" in the enthalpy profile, i.e. the potential energy maximum *is* the final state. Is this logic correct?

If so, then wouldn't the reverse process have no energy barrier? Presumably the only reason this wouldn't be spontaneous at any temperature would be because of entropy changes.

Comment: Please notice that evaporation and vaporisation are not same.

Comment: Yes, you are essentially correct. The vapour pressure above a liquid is give by $P=Ak_BT\exp(-\Delta E/(k_BT))$ where $A$ is a constant and $k_B$ the Boltzmann constant. Experiment shows that plotting $\ln(P/T)$ vs $1/T$ gives a straight line.

Comment: @Rafael Hello Rafael. I would just like to add, that there **is** a jump in the enthalpy profile when liquid vaporizes to gas. In fact, every thermodynamic property ($V$, $A$, $S$, $H$, $U$) at the liquid saturated state suffer an abrupt change into the gas saturated phase. The only exception is the Gibbs Energy $G$. Do you agree? If you don't believe me, you can check the steam tables.